# Does distributed queues also help in load balancing?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I went thru http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-distributed-queues-work.html, and found out that distibuted queues are advantageous when
 if a master fails, clients failover to a slave and you don't loose a message.

Somehow i had one more good point in mind  for distributed queues (say i have 4 distributed queues), then message published will go
to one of the queue to balance the load on each queue. Looks like i had wrong understanding. right?

Is it configurable that if load on specific queue  reaches a specific limit, message gets published on another distributed queue?

**Update:-** as per http://activemq.apache.org/clustering.html clustering of brokers exist but did not find queue clustering?